# Ajax call works once, but then doesn't update my data (codeigniter)

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a page which displays content in boxes. Above these boxes are four buttons, when clicked they filter the content below it. The first time I press any of the buttons the filter works great, however if I press the button for a second time then it doesn't work.

I am only replacing the filtered content div (the boxes), so the buttons used to filter aren't being replaced. I'm assuming some kind of binding/linking issue but haven't been able to get to the bottom of it.

Any help appreciated.

My view (the console.log in my click function always displays the correct button ID):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

jQuery('.btnSubmit').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var mypage_id = this.id;
    console.log(mypage_id);
    var url = "http://localhost/site/get_list_view";

        $.ajax({

            url: url,
            type: 'POST',               
            data: { my_data: this.id},
            cache: false,
            success : function(data){ 

                if(data){
                     $('.deals').replaceWith(data);
                }
            }
        });

});});
```

My controller (reduced it to just echo my data, and creates a random number every time it's hit - the data and the number never changes after that first hit):

```
public function get_list_view(){

    $my_data = $this->input->post('my_data');
    echo($my_data);
    echo(rand(10,100));}
```

Any tips?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say its because after you run this line:

```
$('.deals').replaceWith(data);
```

the html element with the class ".deals" is totally replaced with your ajax response.  If your ajax response doesn't have a containing element with the ".deals" class it will never work again until you refresh the page.

Also you could simply rewrite that line to say:

```
$('.deals').html(data);
```

and then your response doesn't need to have a ".deals" wrapping class element as you're no longer replacing but filling it with the response.

Without all your code the above is my best guess.  Another guess is that sometimes jquery event handlers do not reattache properly after an ajax refresh of content, in the old days we used "live" to handle that, but its been replaced with a new usage of .on:

```
$( document ).on( events, selector, data, handler );
```

So in your case that would look like:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.btnSubmit', function(e) {
    ... rest of your code
```

Comment: Yep, fixed - I was missing my deal div on the new view. That's three hours I'm never getting back.
Cheers mate.

Comment: glad it helped.. just be glad its not 3 days you're never getting back... :-)

Comment: This has just helped me!

When you say "the html element with the class ".deals" is totally replaced with your ajax response." does this mean that when the ajax response comes next time, it cant find the element where the value has to be updated because the div along with its Id has been replaced by the return value first time?